# Creating and recognition of a vGPU device

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to create a VSI with vGPU. What field in the JSON payload do I pass in on the POST to create a vGPU VSI?  What field in the JSON payload do I interrogate on a get that indicates the VSI is a vGPU device?

Answer (score 0):

To create a new VSI using GPU, you can use this rest api:

Method: POST

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder
```

Body: Json

```
{  
   "parameters":[  
      {  
         "orderContainers":[  
            {  
               "complexType":"SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest",
               "location":"DALLAS13",
               "packageId":835,
               "presetId": 405,
               "prices":[  
                  {  
                     "id":45466
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":2202
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":204853
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":204853
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":204853
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":204853
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":1800
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":273
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":55
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":58
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":420
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":418
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":21
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":57
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":905
                  }
               ],
               "quantity":1
            } 
          ]
      }
   ]
}
```

The GPU option is only available in the DALLAS13 location and you have to add the attribute "presetId", is there where the flavor GPU is added.

The option ACL1 and AC1 are selected for GPU.

e.g

```
AC1.8x60x25
```

it means (8 x 2.0 GHz Cores, 60 GB RAM , 25 GB (SAN) FIRST DISK)

To get the GPU presetId values you can use this rest api:

Method: GET

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package/835/getActivePresets
```

You can search the GPU option by ACL1 o AC1.

The result will be:

```
{
        "description": "AC1.8x60x25\r\n",
        "id": 405,
        "isActive": "1",
        "keyName": "AC1_8X60X25",
        "name": "AC1.8x60x25",
        "packageId": 835
    },
```

And you can use this rest api to know the characteristics of the GPU, searching by the name:

e.g  "name": "AC1.8x60x25"

Method: GET

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getCreateObjectOptions
```

To know that the VSI is a GPU you can use this rest api:

Method: GET

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[virtualGuestId]/getObject?objectMask=mask[billingItem[orderItem[preset]]]
```

You have to search by the preset value.

Comment: I was hoping I didn't have to change my current way of creating a Virtual Guest in SoftLayer.   Today I use the URL https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest with a POST method

Comment: The JSON payload is {
       "parameters" :
  [
           { "hostname" : "garycs-test",
             "domain" : "sl.cloud9.ibm.com",
             "startCpus" : 2,
                    "maxMemory" : 4,
             "hourlyBillingFlag" : "true",
             "operatingSystemReferenceCode" : "CENTOS_7_64",
                    "blockDevices" : [
                    {
                       "device" : "0",
                       "diskImage" :
                       {
                         "capacity" : 100
   I can't post all of teh JSON payload.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rest api to create a new VSI with GPU using the method createObject of the SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest service.

Method: POST

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createObject
```

Body: Json

```
{
    "parameters": [
        {
            "hostname": "test",
            "domain": "test.local",
            "datacenter": {
                "name": "dal13"
                },
            "hourlyBillingFlag": "true",
            "operatingSystemReferenceCode": "CENTOS_7_64",
            "networkComponents": [
                     {
                         "maxSpeed": 1000
                     }
                  ],
            "privateNetworkOnlyFlag": "true",
            "supplementalCreateObjectOptions": {
                         "flavorKeyName": "AC1_8X60X25"
           }
        }
    ]
}
```

You have to add the GPU value in the attribute "flavorKeyName".

To get the "flavorKeyName" you can use the rest api that is above.

"AC1_8X60X25"

it means (8 x 2.0 GHz Cores, 60 GB RAM , 25 GB (SAN) FIRST DISK)